# disabling asp button onclick prevents event from firing

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to disable an asp button when it is clicked on the client side.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Save" class="Button" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CausesValidation="false"></asp:Button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("input[type=submit],button").click(function (){$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");});
</script>
```

when the button is clicked it does post back to the page_load , but it won't go to the btnSubmit_Click method. If I remove the jquery that disables the button it makes it from the page_load to the btnSubmit_Click method.

It seems when the button is disabled from the jquery it is no longer able to wire up to its event. Anyone have any ideas how I can disable the button client side, and still make it to the specific onclick event method?

Comment: What if you disable the button not in button click but in form's submit event?

Comment: When you clicked on the Asp button. need to disable the same in the Client side.. then why can;t you disable the button from the start itslef

Comment: Yea I was disabling the button right after it was clicked so that the user couldn't keep clicking the button and getting back to the server multiple times. Once the page posts back and reloads, the button goes back to its original state of enabled. The issue was I was disabling an input type=submit before the form.submit in my client side code. Apparently that will disable the onclick event, it wasn't going to its onclick method.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved (Yuriy answered), the issue was that I needed to put the disabled code within the form.submit client side code. If not the disabled button was not firing its click event, yet it was still posting back, just not going to the onclick method.

solution:

```
$('#Form1').submit(function(){ $("input[type=submit],button").click(function (){$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");});
```